# How do I retrieve course contents of the specific course in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am creating an online course site. I have issue with retrieving the course content of a specific course.

This function shows all the contents of different courses as well. I want to show the content of a specific course instead.

```
public function index()
{
    $contents = Content::all();
    return view('content.index', compact('contents'));
}
```

This is my content model.

```
class Content extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'topic', 'content',
];

public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
}
}
```

Thsi is course model.

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'about', 'image',
    ];

public function contents(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Content');
}
}
```

Content Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('course_id');
        $table->string('content');
        $table->string('topic');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Content index blade

```
@foreach ($contents as $content)
  <div class="col-lg-12 content-list">
    <a href="/content/{{$content->id}}">
      <div class="cl-item mb-2" style="border-radius: 8px; padding: 18px; background-color: #c2c6ca;">
      <h4 class="m-0">{{$content->topic}}</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: in blade do this `$content->course->name` name is the course name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a route in `web.php` like following:

```
Route::get('/courses/{course_id}/contents', 'ContentController@get')->name('web.course_contents');
```

In the above code base, we pass "course_id" param for which we want to fetch the contents for.

In ContentController.php, do the following:

```
class ContentController extends Controller
{
    get($course_id)
    {
        $contents = Content::where('course_id', $course_id)->get();
        return view('content.index', compact('contents'));
    }
}
```

`Content::where('course_id', $course_id)->get()` will run `select * from contents where course_id = ?` query to your database. You can check this by doing the following:

```
class ContentController extends Controller
{
    get($course_id)
    {
        $contents = Content::where('course_id', $course_id)->get();
        logger(Content::where('course_id', $course_id)->toSql());
        return view('content.index', compact('contents'));
    }
}
```

You can learn more about Laravel Query Builders [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries).

Happy Coding!

Comment: <a href="/content" class="site-btn buy-bbtn">View Content</a> how can I get this button work fine in this solution?

Comment: you can use this <a href=" {{ URL('/content/'.$content->id )}}" class="site-btn buy-bbtn"> to pass id to your route.

Comment: You can do <a href="{{ route('web.course_contents', ['course_id' => $course->id]) }}" class="site-btn buy-bbtn">

Comment: <a href="/courses/{{$courses->id}}/contents" class="site-btn buy-bbtn">View Content</a>  This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

For this, all you need to do is use with to fetch both contents and their courses at the same time as:

```
public function index()
{
    $contents = Content::with('course')->get();
    return view('content.index', compact('contents'));
}
```

For more information, you can visit this link: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: what changes I have to do in blade? I have updated the blade also in question

Comment: no, it's not working. I think there is something wrong with foreach

Comment: in your blade file you can simply do this {{$content->course->title}}

Comment: I misspelled content as contents you can access it by using {{$content->course->title}}

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9ZNzS11 look content is working fine. but the last one is of other course

Comment: Look the query that I wrote retrieve contents and their associated course information can you please state clearly what you need cuz the link above seems to work fine

Comment: I have course_id in content table. I want to show the contents only of the course which is clicked.

Comment: I thought you meant you want to load both contents and courses at the same time. Sorry, my bad. for your problem the above solution provided by Vinayak is correct